# Manjaro Linux after update 2015/10/08 USB keybord + mouse not working

Tags: linux, keyboard, archlinux

I'm running the latest manjaro-version on my thinkpad x220. after the update yesterday (2015/10/08 *) my usb-keybord and mouse are not working anymore.

lsubs gives me:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 001 Device 046: ID 046d:c01d Logitech, Inc. MX510 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 045: ID 046a:0023 Cherry GmbH CyMotion Master Linux Keyboard G230
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 040: ID 17ef:100a Lenovo ThinkPad Mini Dock Plus Series 3
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So, as you can see, the mouse (Logitech MX510 Device046) and the keyboard (Device045) are listed but not working.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Georg

*https://manjaro.github.io/Update-2015-10-08_%28stable%29/

Comment: So I just tested my usb-stick: not working. got listed with lsubs but not recognized

Comment: try to change to another usb 2.0

Comment: sadly, doesnt help but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding *Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"* to */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mhwd.conf* solved the problem for me.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
   ...
   Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
EndSection
```

Not sure thought if that's a good solution as 90-mhwd.conf will most likely be overwritten by mhwd on future updates.

Comment: In my case using AutoAddDevices in false disabled a lot of things ... but I tried an option that seems to be working ... details about it in an additional answer

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchProduct "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
    Option "XkbLayout" "de"
    Option "XkbVariant" "deadtilde"
EndSection
```

For getting the name of the product you can use `lsusb -vv` or the commands `hwinfo` or `udevadm info -a /dev/input/by-id/*`.

Alternatively you can also match by vendor using MatchVendor too.

By the way you may wan to change the XkbLayout from "de" to "es" or and keyboard language layout you have and also change (or remove) the XkbVariant according to your keyboard.

You can add something similar for the mouse.

I hope it works !!